# Function for increasing percentage each period while compounding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for how to do some odd compounding, where the rate also changes each period. I'd like a function of

- initial balance
- percentage rate that's added the first *and every period*
- and a number of periods after which we want our new balance

The worst loan contract ever? I arrived at this problem via a [spreadsheet question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129269) over on Web Apps SE talking about scores rather than money. Given that spreadsheet context, I dodged the math and just iteratively pre-calculated every period's percentages. It screamed at me that I should be able to work up a simple algebraic approach for a self-contained function.

For a non-financial example, these are the variables from that question restated for my terms:

- a student's total grade this quarter as 0 to 100 points
- the penalty percent according to school policy
- that student's absences this quarter

But again here, that penalty is to both have a compounding effect on score, but also increase after every application. So say a student had a perfect score, but three absences, and the rule is "8% penalty *per absence* per absence":

1. $100$ points to start
2. $100 - ( \mathbf{0.08} \times 100 ) = 92$ left after $1$ absence
3. $92 - ( \mathbf{0.16} \times 92 ) = 77.28$ after $2$
4. $77.28 - ( \mathbf{0.24} \times 77.28 ) = 58.73$ after $3$. Brutal! Don't be absent.

So it's compounding, since the input each iteration is the remaining score after the previous absence, but adapting the everyday compounding formula

$$\text{score}_1=\text{score}_0\times(1-\text{penalty} ) ^{\text{absences}}$$

naturally doesn't account for the changing penalty rate across the above steps 2 to 4. Those increasing penalties could be expressed as $(0.08\times\text{absences})$, but that would always use the total absences, not the required piecemeal increase for each exponentiation. I suppose it can't be exponentiation—the base isn't constant.

Is there a way to achieve this without a series or recursion, just simple algebra? Since this is now "just" a curiosity, if you have an answer please at least briefly explain how it works. Also, I cannot upvote you twice but extra esteem and gratitude to you if it is translatable to a native spreadsheet function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b(t) balance after t cycles.
p(t) percent added for the t-th cycle.
pt(t) percent for the t-th cycle.
pt(t) = p(0) + p(1) + p(2) ... + p(t-1)

b(0) = b, p(0) = p.
b(t+1) = b(t) + b(t).pt(t)
b(t) = b + b(0).pt(1) + b(1).pt(1) ... + b(t-1).pt(t-1)

Since p(t) is arbitrary, no simplifications are possible.

Comment: Oh thank goodness. I wrote them up as [somewhat different] functions too and couldn't get to the point you did—where I was convinced it couldn't be simplified. Answer acceptance pending any other answers/comments. Thanks for the clarity.